# Best way to specify username for NetLocalGroupAddMembers after using NetUserAdd, CreateWellKnownSid and LookupAccountSid

Tags: c, winapi

Well, I just wanted to create an user with `NetUserAdd` function, but I figured out that I also had to add him to the Users group to be able to sign in.

I called `CreateWellKnownSid` to get the SID for the Users group and `LookupAccountSid` to get the string game for that SID.

This is a portion of my code:

```
addUser = NetUserAdd(NULL, infoLevel, (LPBYTE)&userData, &paramError);

    if (addUser != NERR_Success)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"\nA system error has ocurred: %d\n", addUser);

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        //Let's allocate memory for the SID
        if (!(groupSID = LocalAlloc(memAttributes, sidSize)))   //if fails
        {
            wprintf(L"\nMemory allocation failed: \n");
            ShowError(GetLastError());
            exit(1);

        }

        //Let's create a SID for Users group
        if (!CreateWellKnownSid(sidType, NULL, groupSID, (DWORD*)&sidSize))
        {
            fwprintf(stderr, L"\nError getting the SID: \n");
            ShowError(GetLastError());
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {

            //Converting SID to a readable string

            if (!LookupAccountSidW(NULL, groupSID, name, &nameSize,
                domainName, &domainNameSize, &accountType))
            {
                fwprintf(stderr, L"Error getting name from SID: \n");
                ShowError(GetLastError());
                return 1;

            }




        }

        LocalFree(groupSID);



    }
```

What I need is to add that user to the Users group by using `NetLocalGroupAddMembers`, but the two level of data need the `Domain\Name` format, not just the username. I think I would need to call `GetComputerName` (local computer only); however, I don't know what is the best way to concat the Users group retrieved from `LookAccountSid` with the username, received as argument, to send the `Domain\Name` format the function needs as input for the buffer.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just use level 0 instead? It just needs the users SID.

Comment: I would need to convert the user name passed as argument to SID using `LookupAccountName`, but it requires the same Domain\User format.

Comment: You can pass a plain username to LookupAccountName.